# Make screen capture of PS3 connected to my monitor

Tags: screen-capture, ps3

When I change the input mode of my monitor to the PlayStation 3 (HDMI) and click <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> on my keyboard it takes a screenshot of my desktop computer instead of the game I'm playing.

Does anybody know how I can take a screenshot of the PS3 screen output?

Comment: Your display does not send any signal back to your computer, so there's no way you can capture screenshot with your setup. If you want to capture screenshot and such, you need to buy a capture device (ie: http://www.elgato.com/gaming/game-capture-hd).

Answer (score 0):

The PS3 signal is not passing through your PC.  You would need to run your PS3 through a video input on your PC (rather than connect it directly to the monitor), if you have one, in order to take a screenshot.

Comment: is there any way to do this without using a game capture like @shinjijai say?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.